# Django OneToOneField allow online one reference

Tags: python, django, model

I am trying to create a one to one reference and want to make sure that that reference is not allowed to be used for another model or instance.

For example

Say I have an address model, Person Model and Company Model

Person has a OneToOneField field to Address
Company also has a OneToOneField field to Address

```
address=Address(data="some address")
company=Company(name="some company",address=address)
person=Person(name="my name",address=address)
```

Models:

```
class Address(models.Model):
  data = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
class Company(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
  address=models.OneToOneField(Address,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
  address=models.OneToOneField(Address,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I would like the system to throw an error on this since I am setting the same address to 2 different models.

Also this would delete both person and company if I delete address.

Usually you catch this with code and not make a stupid mistake like this. 
But can system catch it since it is one to one ?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the deletion you could use `on_delete=models.PROTECT`. In the other case you could add `unique=True` so a person id = 1 will have a address id = 1, a person id = 2 can't have a address id = 1 anymore. But it would only solve for one model:
`address=models.ForeignKey(Address, unique=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)`

A new approach would be create a model to reference the address of both company and person and be able to forbid the creation with the same address id:

```
class AddressExample(models.Model):
    id_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, unique=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    id_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    id_company = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Note that I used `blank=True, null=True` so you can create an instance only with a Person or a Company, without the need to create a instance with both. There is a Meta to use combination of primary keys too.

```
class AddressExample(models.Model):
    id_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, unique=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    id_person = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    id_company = models.ForeignKey(Person, blank=True, null=True, unique=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

   class Meta:
       unique_togther = ('id_address', 'id_person', 'id_company')
       # Not sure if it will throw a error here because `id_person` and `id_company` can be blank 
       # or null. But the use of `unique together` is for cases where you want to guarantee 
       # the combination of the primary keys will be unique.
```

Hope it helps.